# Change highlighted background of link in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

Currently, I am using OHAttributedLabel to display some text and I manually configure any URL links in the text to be detected.

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:(id)link range:range];
```

The link is detected and is displayed correctly. When I tap on it, the background color of the attributed string changes to gray color.

My question is - Is there any way to change the highlighted background color of the link to some other color instead of the default gray color.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS the detector link has its own default behavior and you don't have any control on it.